# how to use custom service name in mongodb+srv scheme?

Tags: mongodb, dns, consul

According to the documentation https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v4.4/reference/connection-string/#std-label-connections-dns-seedlist `mongodb+srv://server.example.com/` is equivalent to `_mongodb._tcp.server.example.com` record.

However, I have multiple Mongo services, and I want to connect to `_mymongodb._tcp.server.example.com`. How do I specify to use `mymongodb` service name instead of `mongodb`? I have been staring at the documentation for hours, and I can't seem to find out.

Comment: From reading the source code, I suspect the string `_mongodb._tcp` is hardcoded https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/3e63636e66ced4aed6d1aaaafcdca7ae19cf96f2/src/mongo/client/mongo_uri.cpp#L408 . Is this true?

Comment: When you run multiple mongo services, then they must run on different ports. Just add the port number: `mongodb+srv://server.example.com:27017,server.example.com:27018/`

Comment: Well, then there is no point in using SRV then. SRV DNS entries exist so that I don't have to know the port. I could manually script `dig SRV _mymongodb._tcp.server.example.com | extract host and port | join with comma | xargs mongo`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible, the string `_mongodb._tcp` is prefixed with the host name, and it is hardcoded in the source code. https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/3e63636e66ced4aed6d1aaaafcdca7ae19cf96f2/src/mongo/client/mongo_uri.cpp#L408

The only possible way is to handle that manually, for example in Linux shell with:

```
srvs=$(dig +short SRV _mymongodb._tcp.server.example.com | awk '{print $4":"$3}' | paste -d,)
mongo "mongodb://$srvs/"
```